# Globalize2 Get only translated attributes from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize2

```
    class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
      translates :title, :content
      attr_accessor :rank
    end
```

How I can list only the attributes of the Site model, which work with the translates method ? (in this case, I should get an array with ['title', 'content'], without the rank attribute, because it is not translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translations are stored in a separate table, accessible through the association `globalize_translations`

So, to get those, just do a

```
Site.first.globalize_translations
```

Then you will have to filter out the non-translated columns like `id, site_id, locale, created_at, updated_at` the remaining ones should be the ones that you have translated.

If what you want is to get which attributes that are being translated and not the contents of it, then you can find them in the globalize_options: `Site.globalize_options[:translated_attributes]`